Discounting on SOFR/SONIA/Euribor Options
I'm modelling the price of SOFR/SONIA/EURIBOR options on their corresponding futures. Is there a convention or details on whether discounting should take place or not? If there is no discounting why would that be the case?

Yes, discounting should take place. The derivative of an interest-rate product is still subject to the time value of money.
For these products, I'm fairly certain the discount rate is derived from the product itself, so for EURIBOR, you use the EURIBOR curve.

For discounting, you use the rate that is stipulated in the CSA/collateralisation agreement. For SOFR/SONIA options, this is usually SOFR/SONIA itself. For EURIBOR options, this is commonly ESTR.

Agreed. Do not use a Euribor curve for discounting, but ESTR
